# How can I import Wordnet into a Graph Database like OrientDB,Neo4j,etc.?

Tags: orientdb, wordnet

I have all the RDF/OWL files available for Wordnet here : http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/

I want to import them to the a new graphical database.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good paper (http://www.thinkmind.org/index.php?view=article&articleid=dbkda_2013_1_10_30004) describing a possible approach.